# Permutations of Symmetric Group of Order 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Find an example, in the group $S_3$ of permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$, of elements $x,y\in S_3$ for which $x^2 = e = y^2$ but for which $(xy)^4$ $\not=$ e.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find writing a question that looks like it consists only of a verbatim quote from an exercise sheet to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, a quick correction: The symmetric group $S_3$ is a group of *order* $3! = 6$: the group of all permutations of the elements in the set $S = \{1, 2, 3\}$.

Recall that these elements are the permutations, written in cycle form here, consisting of $$S_3 = \{(1) = e, (1\; 2), (1\; 3), (2\; 3), (1\; 2\; 3), (1 \;3 \;2)\}.$$

There are three elements (permutations) in $S_3$ which have order $2$; and what this means is that, for $x\in S_3$, and $x \neq e$, but $x^2 = e$, then $x$ has order $2$.

These elements (permutations) in $S_3$ that of order two are

$$\;(1 \;2), (1\; 3), (2\; 3).\tag{ Order 2}$$ $$ \text{So}\;(1 \;2)(1 \;2) = e, \text{ and likewise, for each}$$ *Any two* elements of these three elements $x, y, \;\;x \neq y,\;$ are such that $x^2 = e, \; y^2 = e$, but $(xy)^2 \neq e$ and $(xy)^4 \neq e.\quad$

(Recall that $S_3$ is *not* abelian, so $(xy)^2 \neq x^2y^2 = e$ and $(xy)^4 \neq x^4y^4 = e.$)

Try for yourself: take any two *different* permutations of order two, call them $x, y$ respectively, and compose them: find $xy$; then find $(xy)^2$ and $((xy)^2)^2 = (xy)^4$, and you'll have what you need.

Comment: Very nice answer again! +1 No feedback :-(

Answer (score 2):

However, you have to solve the problem theoretically; I 'd like to do it for you by using GAP. Indeed, after solving such this computational problem by using theorems and facts, it is a fun doing that by machine. Here you are:

```
gap> S3:=SymmetricGroup(3);;
gap> o2:=Filtered(S3,x->Order(x)=2);;
gap> eo2:=Elements(o2);
                        [(2,3),     (1,2),     (1,3)]
gap> for i in [1..3] do
         for j in [1..3] do
             if (eo2[i]*eo2[j])^4 <> () then Print(eo2[i],"    ",eo2[j],"\n"); fi;
         od;
     od;

                           (2,3)            (1,2)
                           (2,3)            (1,3)
                           (1,2)            (2,3)
                           (1,2)            (1,3)
                           (1,3)            (2,3)
                           (1,3)            (1,2)
```

Comment: There was an error in the 2nd line using variable `g`. I've fixed it by removing a call to `Elements` completely - one can call `Filtered` with a group being the first argument (provided it may be enumerated). Also, since _xy_ and _yx_ have the same order, there is no need to check both cases. E.g. something like `Filtered(Combinations(Filtered(SymmetricGroup(3),g->Order(g)=2),2), x -> (x[1]*x[2])^4<>());` will suffice. One could also use conjugacy classes to filter all elements of a given order instead of running over the whole group, but I have no space to fit that in the comment ;-)

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: There is nothing to say just saying Thank you, Alexander. :-)

Comment: Nice addition, Babak!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to have $(xy)^3=e$, so that $(xy)^4=(xy)^3(xy)=e(xy)=xy\neq e$.

Comment: Question: Why does $(xy)^3$ = e?

Comment: You want to find $x,y$ with this property, e.g. @Metin's example.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x=(12)$ and $y=(23)$ ...

Answer (score 0):

This group is isomorphic to the 6 element dihedral group. Any element including a reflection will have order two. The product of two different such elements will be a pure nonzero rotation, necessarily of order 3.